# Reflections could not get type for name java.security.interfaces.EdECPrivateKey from any class loader

Tags: spring, java-11, reflections

We are getting this exception in the logs related to Reflections where a file is not available on the classpath. We are not able to find the appropriate maven depdendency to be added for this class to be availabe.

Please note that we are using `REDHAT OPENJDK 11.0.18.10-1`

```
00:47:42:316072|0122-00099:INFO [org.reflections.Reflections] - Reflections took 6223 ms to scan 51 urls, producing 3364 keys and 15403 values 
00:47:43:208290|1587-00099:WARN [org.reflections.Reflections] - could not get type for name java.security.interfaces.EdECPrivateKey from any class loader
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name java.security.interfaces.EdECPrivateKey
    at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:312)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:382)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:140)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:182)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:155)
    at com.iontrading.isf.workflow_engine.impl.grapher.yed.BootstrapWorkflowGrapherService.start(BootstrapWorkflowGrapherService.java:64)
    at com.iontrading.isf.boot.impl.a.start(BootServiceWrapper.java:64)
    at com.iontrading.isf.boot.impl.ServicesContainerImpl.startService(ServicesContainerImpl.java:42)
    at com.iontrading.isf.boot.impl.b.start(BootServices.java:75)
    at com.iontrading.isf.applicationserver.impl.d.a(ISFAppBuilder.java:40)
    at com.iontrading.isf.applicationserver.impl.ISFBootstrap$1$1.run(ISFBootstrap.java:145)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.interfaces.EdECPrivateKey
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:310)
    ... 11 more

00:47:44:455779|1584-00099:WARN [org.reflections.Reflections] - could not get type for name java.security.interfaces.EdECPublicKey from any class loader
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name java.security.interfaces.EdECPublicKey
    at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:312)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:382)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:140)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:182)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:155)
    at com.iontrading.isf.workflow_engine.impl.grapher.yed.BootstrapWorkflowGrapherService.start(BootstrapWorkflowGrapherService.java:64)
    at com.iontrading.isf.boot.impl.a.start(BootServiceWrapper.java:64)
    at com.iontrading.isf.boot.impl.ServicesContainerImpl.startService(ServicesContainerImpl.java:42)
    at com.iontrading.isf.boot.impl.b.start(BootServices.java:75)
    at com.iontrading.isf.applicationserver.impl.d.a(ISFAppBuilder.java:40)
    at com.iontrading.isf.applicationserver.impl.ISFBootstrap$1$1.run(ISFBootstrap.java:145)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.interfaces.EdECPublicKey
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:310)
    ... 11 more
```

We tried searching the web for a subsequent dependency but it seems not available to me.

Comment: [`java.security.interfaces.EdECPrivateKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/interfaces/EdECPrivateKey.html): Since: Java 15.

Comment: The wierd thing is that we are getting this with Java 11 and we are not really sure about it. Anyways thanks for this information @Holger

Comment: I wouldn’t call it weird that you get a `ClassNotFoundException` in Java 11 for a class that doesn’t exist in Java 11 but was introduced in Java 15. Either, this software isn’t supposed to run with earlier Java versions or it contains optional parts not supposed to be used in Java 11, but the Reflections library doesn’t understand such a concept when searching for (all) implementations of a class or interface.